# Why does the msi installer give "System can not find the path specified"?

Tags: python, subprocess, windows-installer

When I run my code, it runs all the commands but the msiexec.exe installers.  When it runs those commands I get the following.

> CompletedProcess(args=['msiexec.exe', '/a
> googlechromestandaloneenterprise64.msi /qn /norestart /lv
> chrome.log'], returncode=1639, stdout='', stderr='')

I have searched through this website and tried all the different ideas that I found but all produced the same result.  I have tried running it in a separate cmd window, same results.

I am running Windows 10 21H2.  Python 3.9.7.

I know the code is messy.  It has been hours of trying different things.  Can someone tell me why MSIEXEC.exe acts differently?

```
import os
import subprocess

def run(name, para):    
    try:
        print(f"Running the following:\n\tProgram: {name}\n\tCommand: {para}\n")
        status =  subprocess.run([name, para], capture_output=True, shell=True, text=True)

    finally:
        return status

class Settings:
    def __init__(self):
        self.timezone = 'Canada Central Standard Time'
        #self.installationsList = [("notepad.exe", "text.txt"), ('calc.exe', '')]
        
        self.installationsList = [('notepad.exe', 'text.txt'),
        ('msiexec.exe', '/i googlechromestandaloneenterprise64.msi /qn /norestart /lv chrome.log'),
        ('Dell-Command-Update-Windows-Universal-Application_601KT_WIN_4.5.0_A00_01.exe /s /e=c:\Temp', ''),
        ('PlantronicsHubInstaller.EXE /quiet /norestart', ''),
        ('msiexec.exe /I 7z2201-x64.msi /qn', ''),
        ('powershell.exe', ' -executionpolicy bypass -file Remove_Mail_Calendar.ps1')]
        
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.timezone

    def LaunchInstallations(self):
        for name,para in self.installationsList:
            print(run(name, para))

    def SetTimeZone(self):
        run(f"powershell.exe Set-TimeZone -Id '{self.timezone}'", '')
        run('W32tm /resync /force', '')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(os.curdir)
    settings = Settings()
    print(settings)
    settings.SetTimeZone() # Setting the local timezone
    settings.LaunchInstallations() # Lauching the list of common installed applications.
    print("Closing Program!")
```

Comment: Foe google chrome, why you are passing /a (Used for admin install) which TARGETDIR as network location but not passed. You might pass /i for normal installation.

Comment: Thanks @VivekJaiswal.  I have tried that.  It made no difference.

Comment: it might not find your "googlechromestandaloneenterprise64.msi" - try to provide the full path for this MSI and also provide a full path for the Log File. Work with "quotes".

Comment: I tried what you suggested but I got the same error. It is only when trying to install msi packages.

Comment: same error for the msi package 7zip ? log file Chrome.log is created ? Error 1639 is "A command-line option passed to the installer is invalid."

Comment: @Christophe  The log file is not created and the 7zip installer acts the same way.